# The result is not same as I expected

Tags: c++

The answer that I want should be 88.5 but it turns out to be 3.60434e+006. I think there's no problem with my quotient formula. What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Grade_one, Grade_two;
    int Average = Grade_one+Grade_two;
    double average = Average/2;

    cout<<"Please input your Grade No.1: ";
    cin>>Grade_one;
    cout<<"Please input your Grade No.2: ";
    cin>>Grade_two;

    if (Grade_one == Grade_two){
        cout<<"Your Grades are Same."<< endl;
    }
    if(Grade_one >= 50 && Grade_two >= 50 && Grade_one <= 74 && Grade_two <= 74){
        cout<<"Hey! You should focus on your study, your grade is concerningly LOW."<< endl;
    }
    else if(Grade_one <= 49 && Grade_two <= 49){
        cout<<"DUDE! you will fail for sure if you don't study."<< endl;
    }
    else if(Grade_one >= 75 && Grade_two >= 75 && Grade_one <= 100 && Grade_two <= 100){
        cout<<average <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

"result"

```
Please input your Grade No.1: 88

Please input your Grade No.2: 89
3.60434e+006

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.238 s

Press any key to continue.
```

The answer should be 88.5. How should I fix this?

Comment: That's undefined behavior. You can't calculate with variables you haven't read. First you have to read the values and then you can calculate `Grade_one+Grade_two`. C++ programming is not like math where you define relations. It's more like a cooking recipe where you tell your computer what to do.

Comment: `int Average = Grade_one+Grade_two;` does not set up some magical means by which `Average` changes whenever `Grade_one` or `Grade_two` changes.   It accesses the current value (at the point in execution where this line occurs) of `Grade_one` and `Grade_two` (which causes undefined behaviour in your code since both `Grade_one` and `Grade_two` are uninitialised) and initialises `Average` with the sum of them.    If `Grade_one` or `Grade_two` is subsequently changed, those changes have no impact on `Average`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Grade_one` and `Grade_two` undefined when you first use them. You also need to cast `Average` to double if you want the result to be double as well.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Grade_one, Grade_two;


    cout<<"Please input your Grade No.1: ";
    cin>>Grade_one;
    cout<<"Please input your Grade No.2: ";
    cin>>Grade_two;
    
    int Average = Grade_one+Grade_two;
    double average = (double)Average/2;

    if (Grade_one == Grade_two){
        cout<<"Your Grades are Same."<< endl;
    }
    if(Grade_one >= 50 && Grade_two >= 50 && Grade_one <= 74 && Grade_two <= 74){
        cout<<"Hey! You should focus on your study, your grade is concerningly LOW."<< endl;
    }
    else if(Grade_one <= 49 && Grade_two <= 49){
        cout<<"DUDE! you will fail for sure if you don't study."<< endl;
    }
    else if(Grade_one >= 75 && Grade_two >= 75 && Grade_one <= 100 && Grade_two <= 100){
        cout<<average <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Average / 2.` could also be used.

Comment: In my opinion, if the result should be double (having decimal places like 88.5), at least one of the `int` operants has to be explicitely casted to double (`Average` or the `2`).

Comment: And that's what replacing `2` with `2.` effectively does. ;) `2` is `int`, `2.` (or `2.0`, for clarity) is `double`.

Comment: Oh ok, I did not know that :)

Comment: @Evg less chars doesn't mean better, I'd suggest `Average / 2.0`. `.0` is less harder to miss that just `.` ;)

Comment: Small comment: when the user specifies a value >100 no answer will follow. Conforming to the message style, It could say *"DUDE ! dream on ! expect values between 0 and 100 for grade, try again."*

Comment: So the use of 2.0 instead of 2 is to know or show the value of decimal?

Comment: @Banana, literal `2` has type `int`, literal `2.0` has type `double`. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals

Answer (score 0):

```
int Grade_one, Grade_two;
int Average = Grade_one+Grade_two;
```

Here, you read uninitialized variables. This is Undefined Behaviour and everything could happen: a crash, trash data, weird behaviour, ...

You need to delay the use of a variable only after you set it to a useful value, e.g.:

```
int Grade_one, Grade_two;

cout<<"Please input your Grade No.1: ";
cin>>Grade_one;
cout<<"Please input your Grade No.2: ";
cin>>Grade_two;

int Average = Grade_one+Grade_two;
double average = Average/2;
```

Comment: And then you'll notice something strange about average being 88 instead of 88.5. Fix it by dividing be `2.0` instead of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating `average` before `Grade_one` and `Grade_two` are initialized, that cannot work (it is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)). If you want to define something now and execute it later thats a function. You can use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) here. `Average` is a misnomer, it is a sum, not an average. You are using integer arithmetics for the division, but to get correct result it has to be calculated with floating points. I think you got the conditions for the `if` right, but the last case is simpler if you just make it an `else` without the condition. Last but not least, you should initialize variables always:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Grade_one = 0;
    int Grade_two = 0;
    auto average = [&](){
        int Sum = Grade_one + Grade_two;
        return Sum / 2.0;        
    };

    Grade_one = 42;
    Grade_two = 12;

    if (Grade_one == Grade_two){
        cout<<"Your Grades are Same."<< endl;
    }
    if(Grade_one >= 50 && Grade_two >= 50 && Grade_one <= 74 && Grade_two <= 74){
        cout<<"Hey! You should focus on your study, your grade is concerningly LOW."<< endl;
    }
    else if(Grade_one <= 49 && Grade_two <= 49){
        cout<<"DUDE! you will fail for sure if you don't study."<< endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<average() <<endl;
              // ^^ call the lambda
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code slightly. Save this piece of universally useful code somewhere (preferably in a header file):

```
  template <class Lam>
  class Expr
  {
      public:
          using ResultType = std::remove_reference_t<decltype((std::declval<Lam>())())>;
          operator ResultType() { return lam(); }
          ResultType value() { return lam(); }
          Expr(Lam&& lam) : lam(std::move(lam)) {}
      private:
          Lam lam;
  };

  #define EXPR(...) Expr([&](){return (__VA_ARGS__) ;})
```

When you `#include` this piece in your program, you can proceed with minimal modifications:

```
int Grade_one, Grade_two;
auto Average = EXPR(Grade_one+Grade_two); // note the auto
auto average = EXPR(Average/2.0);         // and the decimal point
```

I however **strongly** recommend exploring the other answers first.